# Does class initialziation check its member method?

Tags: java, class, initialization

AS the class Log4jImpl below, I want to know whether its' initialization (class initialization not object), will cause `org.apache.log4j.Level` and `org.apache.log4j.Logger` to be initializaton?

---

```
import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Log4jImpl{

  private static final String FQCN = Log4jImpl.class.getName();

  private Logger log;

  public Log4jImpl(String clazz) {
    log = Logger.getLogger(clazz);
  }

  public boolean isDebugEnabled() {
    return log.isDebugEnabled();
  }

  public boolean isTraceEnabled() {
    return log.isTraceEnabled();
  }

  public void error(String s, Throwable e) {
    log.log(FQCN, Level.ERROR, s, e);
  }

  public void error(String s) {
    log.log(FQCN, Level.ERROR, s, null);
  }

  public void debug(String s) {
    log.log(FQCN, Level.DEBUG, s, null);
  }

  public void trace(String s) {
    log.log(FQCN, Level.TRACE, s, null);
  }

  public void warn(String s) {
    log.log(FQCN, Level.WARN, s, null);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intialization of class `Logger` will happen when its static `getLogger` method is invoked: in the constructor of `Log4jImpl`. The initialization of `Level` class will happen when one of its static fields are invoked: `Level.ERROR`, `Level.DEBUG`...

See when class initialization occurs in the [Java language specs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1).

```
interface I {
    public static final int i = 1, ii = Test10.out("ii", 2), kk = Test10.out("kk", 3);
}
interface J extends I {
    int j = Test10.out("j", 3), jj = Test10.out("jj", 4);
}
interface K extends J {
    int k = Test10.out("k", 5);
}
class Test10 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(J.ii);
        System.out.println(K.j);
    }
    static int out(String s, int i) {
        System.out.println(s + "=" + i);
        return i;
    }
}
```

Comment: From "specs", I see "A static field declared by T is used and the field is not a constant variable". But Level.ERROR, Level.DEBUG and so on are "public static final" fields. How to explain?

Comment: @duanjfeng Yes, but if you look at the source code, the constants are initialized with something like: `public static final ERROR = new Level()`

Comment: You mean that class Log4jImpl try to resolve these constants, but they are objects of class Level, so jvm try to load class Level?
(Will you pls tell me more offical reference i can read about this?)

Comment: @duanjfeng The link from java specs above presents an example: 12.4.1-3. I've modified it to show how the `I` interface is initialized if you access `J.ii` in `main`, but is not initialized if you access `J.i`. Please take a look at the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. With you great help, I get to know that Level.ERROR, Level.DEBUG and so on are not constant variable, as java specs say 
"The reference to K.j is a reference to a field actually declared in interface J that is not a constant variable; this causes initialization of the fields of interface J, but not those of its superinterface I, nor those of interface K." 
and 
"A variable of primitive type or type String, that is final and initialized with a compile-time constant expression (§15.28), is called a constant variable."

Answer (score 1):

Using Log4jImpl.class will not load any additional classes.  They will get loaded when you use them in the constructor.

BTW Normally XxxxImpl means you have an implementation of an interface Xxxx

Comment: But actually when I call Class.forName(Log4jImpl.class.getName()), classloader try to load org.apache.log4j.Level.

Comment: `Log4jImpl.class` triggers the class to load.  You want `Class.forName("Log4jImpl", false, null);`

Comment: Why Log4jImpl triggers? Level.ERROR, Level.DEBUG and so on are "public static final" fields.

Comment: To get `Log4jImpl.class` you need to load the class, and possibly the classes it depends on.  Getting it's name and looking it up again will just return this object.